# Разъяснение скрипта WMI

Tags: wmi

Всем привет.
У меня есть задание ознакомиться с примерами скриптов WMI и запустить их.
Проблемы следующие:

1. На [сайте с примером](http://www.askit.ru/custom/progr_admin/m16/lab16_01_wmi.htm) объяснений вообще нету. Пробовал разобраться, но мне кажется, что для первого раза да и вообще первого примера, немного сложновато что-то понять без толковых объяснений. Кое-что пытался понять но увы...
2. Решил хотя бы посмотреть, как будет работать код с примера (переносить записи из журнала событий System на  локальном  компьютере в базу данных EventLog.mdb с полями ComputerName, EventType, EventCode, Message и TimeWritten; после окончания переноса  журнал событий System очищается). У меня выбывает ошибку:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения] А говорили, что скрипты будут выполняться в PowerShell без проблем.
   Или это из-за отсутсвия базы данных?

```
Option Explicit // это начало подключения к WMI
Dim cn, rs, oLocator, oSvc, oColEvents, oColEventLog, Item, oLogFile // создание переменных оболочек объектов?
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") // создаем объект используя оболочку cn (как в Java)?
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data  // видимо делаем преобразовываем в строчку что-то????   
Source=C:\EventLog.mdb" // указыаем источких для обработки данных
cn.Open // не понятно что открываем
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.CursorType = 3
rs.LockType = 3
rs.Open "Events", cn
Set oLocator = CreateObject("wbemScripting.Swbemlocator")
Set oSvc = oLocator.ConnectServer()
Set oColEvents = oSvc.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'System'")
For Each Item In oColEvents
        rs.AddNew
        rs("ComputerName") = Item.ComputerName
        rs("EventType") = Item.Type
        rs("EventCode") = Item.EventCode
        rs("Message") = Item.Message
        rs("TimeWritten") = Item.TimeWritten
        rs.Update
Next
Set oColEventLog = oSvc.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile WHERE LogFileName = 'System'")
For Each oLogFile In oColEventLog
        oLogFile.ClearEventLog
Next
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

В общем прошу о помощи с разъяснением.

Comment: Попробуйте в одну строку написать Set oColEventLog = oSvc.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile WHERE LogFileName = 'System'")

Comment: @AlbertFomin, Вы знаете попробовал сделать это и в других пунктах - помогло. Вот только теперь ошибка не может найти файл EventLog.mdb,  я его так и создал текстовій, и поменял расширение на нужное. Но это ведь неправильно? Или можно, исходя из данного условия делать запись в обычный текстовый файл, ведь у меня нету самой базы данных описанной в примере, точнее нету диска  с ней?

Comment: @AlbertFomin, а видимо не можна там ведь не просто текстовый документ нужен, и методы не для него используются

Comment: Нужна таблица с колонками, такого же типа,как Вы писать будете.MDB - это MS Access база. Можно создать в Access

Comment: @AlbertFomin, а еще какможно сделать? MySQL ведь не подойдет?

Comment: Ну можно и MySQL подключить, только connection string будет другой

Comment: понял,  спасибо за  ваш ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dim cn, rs, oLocator, oSvc, oColEvents, oColEventLog, Item, oLogFile // создание переменных 
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") // Здесь CreateObject создает объект Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Для Connection прописывается Connection Strings с помощью которых он соединяется с базой MS Access
Source=C:\EventLog.mdb" // указываем путь к базе (источник данных)
cn.Open // Открываем Connection, теперь мы можем работать с базой
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset") - Создаем объект RecordSet
rs.CursorType = 3
rs.LockType = 3
rs.Open "Events", cn // открываем таблицу events в нашем Connection, то есть сейчас при помощи rs управляем этой таблицей
Set oLocator = CreateObject("wbemScripting.Swbemlocator") //Создаем объект Swbemlocator 
Set oSvc = oLocator.ConnectServer() // соединяемся  с сервером
Set oColEvents = oSvc.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'System'") // выполняем запрос: выбор все записей для логфайла System 
For Each Item In oColEvents // цикл обработки по записям
        rs.AddNew  // добавили новую строку в таблицу
        rs("ComputerName") = Item.ComputerName
        rs("EventType") = Item.Type
        rs("EventCode") = Item.EventCode
        rs("Message") = Item.Message
        rs("TimeWritten") = Item.TimeWritten
        rs.Update // присвоили и обновили, 
Next // цикл завершен 
Set oColEventLog = oSvc.ExecQuery _
("Select * from Win32_NTEventLogFile WHERE LogFileName = 'System'")
For Each oLogFile In oColEventLog
        oLogFile.ClearEventLog // чистим eventlog
Next
WScript.Echo "Done"`

Comment: премного вам благодарен буду разбираться. Если, что-то все таки не пойму - спрошу еще

Comment: а что такое "ADODB" это тип пожключения? и где делся "Option Explicit"?

Comment: Алгоритм примерно таков. Открывается база, открывается таблица, создается объект подключения к WMI, через WMI запросы получаются данные, которые пишутся в таблицу. Чтобы открыть базу используется Connection strings для каждой  СУБД они свои. Работа с данными идёт при помощи ado

Comment: ADO - грубо говоря интерфейс от Microsoft для доступа к базе. Option Explicit - это примочка Basic

Comment: спасибо, разбираюсь дальше

Comment: и она не играет особой роли?

Comment: нет, это относится к объявлению переменных

Comment: ага, еще раз спасибо

Comment: а гляньте, если вас не затруднит: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594440/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-wmi-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b1