# Скрипт WMI для отслеживания состояния служб

Tags: wmi

Всем примет.
Есть скрипт, который выполняет функцию, описанную выше.
Если я его запущу через PowerShell, в пункте "раз в 10 секунд" будет выбивать ошибку?
И правильно ли я понимаю (хотя бы частично код)? Объясните непонятные моменты.

```
Dim oLocator, oSvc, oColServices, oService // переменные
Set oLocator = CreateObject("wbemScripting.Swbemlocator") // создаем объект Swbemlocator
Set oSvc = oLocator.ConnectServer() // соеденяемся с сервером
Set oColServices = oSvc.ExecNotificationQuery _ // что-то с оповещением
("Select * from __instancemodificationevent " _
    & "within 10 where TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Service'") // событийный запрос с интервалом в 10 секунд
Do 
Set oService = oColServices.NextEvent // ???
        WScript.Echo oService.TargetInstance.Name & vbTab & vbTab & _  
oService.TargetInstance.State
Loop
```

Comment: неужели вопрос настолько глуп?

Comment: кстати, запустил скрипт, работает, заваливает сообщениемя о старте остановке служб. Главное только знать как выключить :) но это уже второй вопрос. Я его через диспетчер процессов зарубил быстро.

Comment: @AlbertFomin, не могу похвастать умениями в области администрирования. В общем у меня вылетает ошибка, пишет строка 4 символ 96 - **недопустимый знак**. Это связано с пробелом? Там его не должно быть? И зачем применяються "`_`"?

Comment: я все написал в одну строку, где можно, _ это склейка строки в визуал бейсике. А в повершелл такого нет, он скорее всего на это и ругается. В командных средах - одна строка, одна команда.

Comment: @AlbertFomin, хорошо. Удалил подчеркивание, теперь пишет "**метод не поддерживаеться объектом ExecNotifiсationQuery**" (строка 4, символ 1).

Comment: где подчеркивания "_", надо переносить на предыдущую строку, склеивать с тем что в конце...  Посмотрите файл, я его подредактировал и запустил  https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/53345502/script.vbs

Comment: так и делал. Запустил предоставленный вами код. Видимо работает. Просто ничего не выводит - значит никаких изменений в работе служб не было?

Comment: и там ведь скрипт надо останавливатьвручную, а как это сделать кроме как диспетчером задач?

Comment: Ну после часа- двух работы системы почти все службы также уже и работают. Можно остановить какую-нибудь службу через services.msc. Вот как остановить скрипт честно говоря не знаю, ну а кому щас легко...

Comment: благодарю и за это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос специфический [касается событий WMI](http://www.askit.ru/custom/sql2005_admin/m9/09_04_06_wmi_events.htm),

`ExecNotificationQuery` - назначает oColServices получателем событий

`__instancemodificationevent`  - тип события для которого отлавливаются изменения.

`TargetInstance isa 'Win32_Service'` - отлавливаются изменения состояния служб.

Within - отвечает за polling interval, то есть теоретически раз в 10 секунд должен запускаться скрипт.

NextEvent - переход к следующему объекту (код на обработку следующего события)

oService.TargetInstance.State - состояние сервиса